# Как открыть текстовый редактор Vim в отдельном окне?

Tags: vi, vim, linux

В терминале ввожу vi, а программа открывается в окне терминала. Как открыть его в отдельном окне?

Comment: Много разных правильных ответов. Если они не удовлетворяют до конца, то придётся поподробнее описать условия работы: терминал в linux/windows, запущен ли xserver, с какими параметрами собран vim (вывод команды :ve) и т.д. При максимально благоприятной комбинации условий достаточно ввести команду `:gui` или `:gvim`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

vim (vi) - консольный редактор, чтобы открыть его в отдельном окне нужно установить для него графическую оболочку. Под Gnome это будет vim-gnome, как будет под другими GUI сказать не могу, но смотрите в сторону пакета gvim.

Answer (score 5):

Запустите эмулятор терминала в фоне, в его параметрах задайте vi file. Linux под рукой нет,
но что-то вроде

```
xterm -e vi my-file &
```

Comment: Ответ подразумевает работу под XWindows в окошке xterm. Другие варианты навскидку: ssh (telnet и пр. не вспоминаем) в консоли (без xserver'а), виндовый ssh (напр. putty).

Answer (score 0):

Вим может открываться только в терминале. Как вариант можно перейти на другой терминал и открыть вим там.